# How to display python dictionary in a Django template in bullet list format?

Tags: python, html, django

How do I alter the following Django template code:

```
<ul> 
 {% for key, value in real_prices.items %} #real_prices is a dictionary
   <li>Price: {{ key }}, link: {{value}}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

To display the dictionary items on a page like this:

- Price: key, link: value
- Price: key, link: value
- Price: key, link: value
- and so on...

The current code only displays the dictionary as a whole.

For reference, here's the view:

```
def test(request):
    prices = []
    real_prices = []
    links = []
    url = 'https://www.airbnb.pl/s/Girona--Hiszpania/homes?refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=Girona%2C%20Hiszpania&place_id=ChIJRRrTHsPNuhIRQMqjIeD6AAM&checkin=2018-04-04&checkout=2018-04-22&children=0&infants=0&adults=2&guests=2&allow_override%5B%5D=&price_max=252&room_types%5B%5D=Entire%20home%2Fapt&min_beds=0&s_tag=Ph6ohhjw'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

    #prices
    page_selectors = soup.select('._1bdke5s')
    print(len(page_selectors))
    last_page_selector = page_selectors[len(page_selectors) - 4]##############-15
    last_page_selector = last_page_selector.getText()
    for x in range(0, int(last_page_selector)):
        response = requests.get(url + '&section_offset=' + str(x))
        response_text = response.text
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response_text)
        spans = soup.select('._hylizj6 span')
        for i in range(0, len(spans)):
            prices.append(spans[i].getText())
        for price in prices:
            if 'zł' in price:
                real_prices.append(price)

        #links
        a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
        for tag in a_tags:
            if '_15ns6vh' in str(tag.get('class')):
                link = 'https://www.airbnb.pl' + str(tag.get('href'))
                links.append(link)

    dictionary = dict(zip(real_prices, links))
    context = {'dictionary': dictionary}
    return render(request, 'javascript/test.html', context)
```

Comment: show your view.

Comment: That code will work fine with a normal dictionary. If you're seeing something else, you should show exactly what you see, and what real_prices is.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the view code to my question.

Comment: Where is the rest of the view? Exactly what is it you're sending to the template, `real_prices` or `dictionary`?

Comment: Apologies, added now. Now I can see that in the template there should be `dictionary.items` instead of `real_prices.items`, but the result is still the same.

Comment: You're passing a dictionary named `dictionary` to the template, not `real_prices`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `real_prices` with `dictionary` and it will work. There is no key named `real_prices` in your context dict, so it won't work.

```
<ul> 
    {% for key, value in dictionary.items %}
        <li>Price: {{ key }}, link: {{ value }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```